# How to block loading https server resource on http pages in Firefox?

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions, adblock, noscript

I wish to block loading of https resources in Firefox on pages that are served via http protocol.

Think of these elements to be blocked/filtered:

- img src="https://*"
- script src="https://*"
- iframe src="https://*"
- frame src="https://*"

I could imagine writing an Adblock Plus "Ad Blocking Rule"/filter that blocks all these request only on http protocol pages.

How to block loading mixed content in Firefox?

Comment: Have you made any attempts to write this filter rule, other than just the list you provided?  If so, what have you tried and where did they fail?

Comment: Don't know how to limit the filter to http:// sites/domains/served pages.

Comment: Adblock Plus has an active forum with a section specifically for filter rule writing: <https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewforum.php?f=2> Have you asked there too?

Comment: @K.A. The forum thread [Blocking HTTP content when using HTTPS](https://adblockplus.org/forum/viewtopic.php?t=8984) is most relevant. The ABP developer confirms that _"blocking mixed content is generally a bad idea"_.

Answer (score 0):

Since Firefox version 18 you don't need an extension to **block mixed content** on https sites.

Enable mixed content blocking in about:config, by setting these two values to `true`:

1. `security.mixed_content.block_active_content`
2. `security.mixed_content.block_display_content`

Source: http://techdows.com/2012/11/make-firefox-18-beta-to-block-mixed-content-on-https-websites.html

Answer (score 0):

Create a "user defined" [NoScript Firefox extension](http://noscript.net/) rule in the Application Boundary Enforcer (Options > Advanced > ABE) section like:

```
Site http:
Deny INC from https:

Site https:
Deny INC from http:
```